# What is conditional probability?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, probability

I need help understanding conditional probability. I was reading an answer here which talks about conditional probability. But, frankly I do not know what it is.

Comment: See [Conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability).

Comment: The term you are using implies that any condition of sense verification can be falsified. That is, all sciences do is Express probability-- not certainty.   There is no such thing as a perfect science (aka a science that gets correct answers 100 percent of the time). Science can never reach 100 percent accuracy by definition. So science and probabilities are a hand in hand relationship. You cant have one without the other. Conditional statements are of the form IF . . . THEN . . . Many humans confuse that form with sufficient & necessary relationships. This is not 100 percent true.

Comment: I cannot tell whether you are asking an elementary question about how conditional probability is defined, or whether you have some more sophisticated question about the relationship between probability and conditionalisation. If the latter, you might wish to read: Alan Hájek, "What Conditional Probability Could Not Be" Synthese, Vol. 137, No. 3 (Dec., 2003), pp. 273-323.

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia may be a good place to go for initial information on this.  Here is what it says:

> In probability theory, conditional probability is a measure of the probability of an event occurring given that another event has occurred.

This tells us that there are two events involved. We want to find a measure for the probability of one event, A, given that another event, B, has occurred.  The article continues:

> If the event of interest is A and the event B is known or assumed to have occurred, "the conditional probability of A given B", or "the probability of A under the condition B", is usually written as P(A | B), or sometimes P<sub>B</sub>(A) or P(A / B).

This gives us a way to write the conditional probability symbolically. It would be represented by *P(A | B)* where P means probability and the A | B part shows that we want the probability of event A given that event B has occurred.  The article then provides an example:

> For example, the probability that any given person has a cough on any given day may be only 5%. But if we know or assume that the person has a cold, then they are much more likely to be coughing. The conditional probability of coughing by the unwell might be 75%, then: P(Cough) = 5%; P(Cough | Sick) = 75%

This may be a place to start to understand the topic.

---

Wikipedia contributors. (2019, June 10). Conditional probability. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 13:03, July 25, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Conditional_probability&oldid=901245667

Answer (score 3):

In colloquial terms, conditional probability tries to capture the idea that context matters. For instance, if we ask how likely it is we will be robbed in the coming year, we can do the math: I've seen numbers like a 0.15% chance that any given person will be robbed in any given year. But obviously that's not the same for everyone, everywhere. Someone who lives in a rural farmhouse is far less likely to be robbed than someone who lives in an urban apartment; people who live in 'good' parts of a city are less likely to be robbed than people who live in 'bad' parts of a city; people who stay indoors a lot are less likely to be robbed than people are always out in public. Depending on *conditions*, the probability of an event might change.

Of course, as they teach probability is school they will give you a lot of simplified, abstract systems where you can calculate exact conditional probabilities: e.g. if you have 12 m&ms (5 red, 4 green, 3 yellow), the probability of drawing a red m&m is 5/12, but the probability of drawing a red m&m *if you refuse to accept a yellow one* (a condition) is 5/9. But don't let the math headaches blind you to the idea that you are merely changing the context of the question.

Comment: I think inverts importance--conditional probability is abstract, exact, and (quite) mathematical. It can *sometimes* be applied to capture the idea of context, broadly speaking.

Comment: Conditional probability exists anywhere there is a context shift. The exact mathematical solutions only exist in special cases, or in real world cases where we can use mathematically accessible approximations. The real world always comes first; abstract models have to conform to the real world, not the other way around.

Comment: @TedWrigley I think the point rather is that there is no probability in the real world. There is only context. Probability is in fact an abstraction from the frequency of events and **always** a mathematical, exact thing. This does not mean that it is not helpful to consider *conditional* as meaning *under relevantly different conditions*, i.e. in different context. But one should be aware that while this is helpful to understand the concept, probabilities do not "exist", they are useful mathematical approximations to describe processes.

Comment: In fact, you don't even have to think of it as an abstraction, or a useful approximation. For example, lots of people think of probability in terms of the Kolmogorov axioms, which have nothing intrinsically to do with likelihood, propensity, or the real world.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking: re: "I think the point rather is that there is no probability in the real world." This is a fairly strange statement, philosophically speaking. There is clearly *uncertainty* in the world, because we have imperfect knowledge. Probability is a mathematical tool that tries to help us cope with uncertainty. Probability exists in exactly the same way that a hammer does; we make such things because they are useful. Even if the world is perfectly deterministic (separate argument there), *we still don't know* what event is coming next.

Comment: @TedWrigley I think the confusion here is between probability as a mathematical concept and as an intuitive concept. The first is a purely formal, abstract idea (how Philip and I see it). The second is as the way we cope with uncertainty (how you see it). They can be connected in useful ways, but they're quite distinct and have no reliance on each other.

Comment: @JohnHughes: I understand the distinction you're making, and it's valid, but it misses the big picture. Probability and statistics are tools for quantifying and measuring uncertainty. That's all they are; that's all they do. Talking about probability divorced from the concept of uncertainty is like talking about freeways divorced from the concept of cars. We can do it, sure — freeways are long strips of asphalt that run between and through cities — but it misses the essence of the thing.